# What is concept of degree at B-spline curve?

Tags: curve, concept, degrees, bspline

Thanks to you attention to my question.

My question is what is concept of degree at B-spline curve as you as seen from the title.

In the book that I am studying, only 'Degree' is given as a factor that changes the shape of the curve.

I searched on the internet, but the results were not good.

If you know B-spline curve's degree concept, please answer that concept to me.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A b-spline curve is basically a piecewise continuous polynomial curve. The degree is the degree of the polynomial. Besides degree, you also need control points and knot vector in order to fully define a b-spline curve.